# Reposition elements in Wordpress post editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a wordpress website and I've added some custom fields. They work just fine, but I wanted to reposition them in the admin editor.

So for example you have the WYSIWYG editor with some little widgets on the side, like categories, publish widget and so on. Some of my custom fields are just checkboxes, so I was wondering if it was possible to put those in the admin sidebar, rather than sticking them underneath the WYSIWYG editor.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

```
add_meta_box( 
    $id, 
    $title,
    $callback, 
    $post_type, 
    $context, 
    $priority, 
    $callback_args 
);
```

**`$context`** - The part of the page where the edit screen section should be shown ('normal', 'advanced', or 'side').

Comment: Let me now if you have some problems